# I cant run my Flutter in android after i update plugin in build.gradle

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I was update the build.gradle app src to make it can insert my json file for firebase

```
plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

then, when i run for android it get error in another build.gradle, it sounds like

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file 'I:\proyekflutter\Autofarm\android\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'I:\proyekflutter\Autofarm\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\7hv98g1d2kpk3a9ag2a4k63hm).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '*BuildScript*' class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @42d80b78)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

the build file is

```
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
```

}

Comment: What can i do to insert my json file to my flutter?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> plugins {
>     id "com.android.application"
>     id "kotlin-android"
>     id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
>     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // This throws an error
> }
> ```

It appears that there is an error in the way you are applying the `'com.google.gms.google-services'` plugin in your Gradle build file. To rectify this issue, you should explicitly use the '`id`' keyword when declaring the plugin:

Here is the corrected code:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

For more info, please visit the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html).